# Arthur C. Clarke novel, the prologue involves a planet with sea creatures?

Tags: story-identification, novel, arthur-c-clarke

The sea creatures are segregated by a land ridge. The females live on one side, the males on the other. During mating season, the males jump the ridge. There is a land species that for some reason wants to prevent this. They build a wall to act as a barrier over the ridge. The creatures are unable to jump it.

The prologue ends with a space ship taking specimens of the soon-to-become-extinct sea creatures. Possibly as some kind of ark operation? I was only able to browse the prologue of this novel and am desperate to know its title.

Answer (score 7):

[*Cradle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cradle_%28novel%29), by Arthur C. Clarke and Gentry Lee, 1988

> The waters of the emerald oceans begin to surge forward in tidal
>   frenzy, now rapidly moving up the rocky cliffs on the western side and
>   quickly submerging great chunks of land on the sloping side that runs
>   to the eastern ocean. The concerted pull of all the moons produces a
>   tide that will eventually cover the isthmus completely, uniting the
>   two oceans. As the waters draw ever closer together, the music from
>   the thousand singing serpents swells to magnificence... It is also a
>   plaintive sound of longing and anticipation, the universal cry of
>   long-suppressed desire on the verge of being satisfied.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for that, now I get why I couldn't find it before. Its a co-author job with Gentry Lee :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only part of this book Clarke wrote is that prologue.  Be prepared for disappointment.